# Exception Handling doesn't work

Tags: c++, exception, marmalade

I am trying to use `try-catch` blocks to handle a `divide-by-zero` exception in marmalade, but I guess marmalade overrides c++ exception handling, so it's not working. I've searched on the forums and the solution seems to be that I have to add one option in the mkb as explained in this [post](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/node/291).

```
options
{
    enable-exceptions=1
}
```

I already tried adding it, but it's not working too. Is there any way I can handle this exception?

Comment: That's not valid C++.  I have no idea what you're trying to do.  C++ has no divide by zero exception.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: it seems that marmalade is a specific framework, and this is the configuration file.

Comment: @CrazyEddie I am currently getting this exception - Unhandled exception at 0x02435baf (XXX.s86) in s3e_simulator_debug.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero. I didn't know that c++ don't have this exception.

Comment: @Creator - That is not a C++ exception but a (simulated?) hardware exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing an extension for the marmalade exceptions will not work.
What the

```
options
{
    enable-exceptions=1
}
```

does is adds a compiler options /GX for msvc and --exceptions for RVCT.
So if you are using some other compiler like g++ it will not work.