# How to catch exceptions (gcc arm c++)

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, arm, marmalade

I use marmalade sdk and there is no support for structured exceptions handling. I need to catch any exception (null pointer, devision by zero or any else) and do some actions before app will crashed (send crash report). How can I do this in native c++ under gcc-arm compiller?

Comment: What did you try? Where did it fail??

Comment: There is a bug in game app, but it don't repeats after reload and doing the same thing. I want to store some last game actions that user done before app crashes and send it by email after that.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to catch any exception

To do so you can use the ellipsis syntax of `catch`:

```
try {
    doStuff(); // May throw
}
// catch all exceptions derived from std::exception
catch(const std::exception& ex) { 
    std::cerr << "Caught exception: '" << ex.what() << "'" << std::endl;
}
catch(...) { // catch everything but unkown
}
```

Also ensure that your build system **doesn't suppress** exceptions and RTTI explicitly with the `-fno-exceptions` and `-fno-rtti` compiler flags.

Comment: int main()
{
 try
 {
  int* p = NULL;
  *p = 5;
 }
 catch (...)
 {
 }
}

//this code doesn't work as this is not standard c++ exception, but I need catch such exceptions

Comment: Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer doesn't throw an exception. It's just UB to do so. I'm afraid you'll need to put `assert()` calls in your code to catch up with such errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've already asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732418/exception-handling-doesnt-work). I tried it with the flag `enable-exceptions=1` in `options`. But it never worked for me. There was a thread on Marmalade regarding the exception handling and it was mentioned there that Marmalade doesn't support them and it was demanded by the community to include this.

Comment: enable-exceptions works only for standard c++ exception, but null pointer and segmentation fault is not c++ exceptions. I tried to catch segmentation fault signal, but signal handler not call in marmalade. May be there is any configs for compiller in icf file or anywhere else to turn signals on?